# TypeORM Entity Schema: referencedColumnName error when saving on cascade as it is an object

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

I'm having some issues with TypeORM and relations. Specifically when it comes to save on cascade I'm getting an error.

I have two related entities as follows:

```js
const ReviewEntity = new EntitySchema<Review>({
    name: 'Review',
    tableName: 'reviews',
    target: Review,
    columns: {
        id: {
            type: 'uuid',
            primary: true,
            transformer: ValueObjectTransformer(ReviewID)
        },
        username: {
            type: 'character varying',
            transformer: ValueObjectTransformer(ReviewUser)
        },
        rating: {
            type: 'integer',
            transformer: ValueObjectTransformer(ReviewRating)
        }
    },
    relations: {
        movie: {
            type: 'many-to-one',
            target: 'Movie',
            joinColumn: {
                name: 'movie_id'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```js
const MovieEntity = new EntitySchema<Movie>({
    name: 'Movie',
    tableName: 'movies',
    target: Movie,
    columns: {
        id: {
            type: 'integer',
            primary: true,
            transformer: ValueObjectTransformer(MovieID)
        },
        title: {
            type: 'character varying',
            transformer: ValueObjectTransformer(MovieTitle)
        },
        poster: {
            type: 'character varying',
            transformer: ValueObjectTransformer(MoviePoster)
        },
        overview: {
            type: 'character varying',
            transformer: ValueObjectTransformer(MovieOverview)
        },
        releaseDate: {
            name: 'release_date',
            type: 'date',
            transformer: ValueObjectTransformer(MovieReleaseDate)
        }
    },
    relations: {
        reviews: {
            type: 'one-to-many',
            target: 'Review',
            cascade: true,
            inverseSide: 'movie'
        }
    }
});
```

Then, when I perform a save:

```js
async save (movie: Movie): Promise<void> {
    const repository = await this.repository();
    await repository.save(movie);
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
query: 'INSERT INTO "reviews"("id", "username", "rating", "movie_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)',
  parameters: [
    'c2dfdc73-47c0-43c4-95e4-e914125160c1',
    'mark_08',
    10,
    MovieID { value: 984984 }
  ],
driverError: error: invalid input syntax for type integer: "{"value":984984}"
```

As you can see, it's taking the `MovieID` as a literal object ignoring the transformer.

Do you know how can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

PD: `MovieID` is what we call in DDD, a value object. It has `toString` method but it doesn't seem to work.